# Host UDP Multicast Online, possible?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, multicast, host

I have made a server that uses UDP multicast sockets.

I am able to run the server on my local host and try with as many clients as I want.

The problem is that i'm new to UDP and multicast and now I need to connect to another pc using the internet.

For example:

```
group = InetAddress.getByName(sendAdd);
buf = senddata.getBytes();
packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, group, senderPort);
```

Is there anyway to host the UDP multicast server online?
What InetAddress should I use in that case?

Comment: Unlikely as with IPv4 multicast is optional and frequently disabled to prevent network storms.  Of course it is used for various services such as video-on-demand and large scale conferences but strictly limited.

Comment: @Steve-o Strange attitude, isn't it. Multicast was invented to *reduce* network storms. You'd think they would disable UDP that *isn't* multicast, apart from the essential services of course.

Comment: @EJP unfortunately multicast has no congestion control, it is a one way resource consumer.  Hence many attempts at implementing a standard reliable multicast, e.g. [PGM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatic_General_Multicast).  Do note that IPv6 mandates multicast by default and so may see better uptake.

Comment: Well can I at least host a UDP server without multicast binded to my machines real ip?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is that there is no way of hosting a multicast server online. Rather than simulating a local network using f.e "hamachi" or any other software.