# Using Multicast Sockets Online

Tags: java, networking, multicast, multicastsocket

I am attempting to create a server that receives an audio feed through a datagram socket and streams this audio to different listeners. I was originally doing this by having another datagram socket waiting for the listeners to ask to join in and then creating a dedicated datagram sockets for them, adding it to an array and when I sent the audio I just looped through all the array to send the audio. Probably not very efficient but it was working originally (although now for a yet unknown reason it is not working online although it works perfectly on my local network).

I decided to do a little more research into Multicast sockets as they seem ideal for what I'm trying to do, however I am confused about a few points, specifically the fact that it appears that you can only use multicast sockets with the following range of IP addresses: 224.0.0.0 - 234.255.255.255.

That is no problem in a local network but I don't understand how this would work on the web, if I can't use my server's IP address, do I just stream the audio to an ip address in that range with a random port I can choose and just have the listeners join that group?

If that's the case how can I know if someone else isn't using that same ip address and port to also stream some sort of data? I have tried searching an answer for this but haven't come across any decent answer. The answer to this question in stackoverflow simply says it's not possible: [Host UDP Multicast Online, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224270/host-udp-multicast-online-posible) but then again I have read and seen countless tutorials that mention one of the main uses for multicast sockets are internet radio stations, for example this youtube tutorial says it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yre19cIpYrQ on minute: 15:27.

If that is the case it must be possible, but I just can't get a decent answer on how this would work. If you could take some time to explain this to me I'd be pretty grateful!

Comment: Multicast address dynamic reservation has RFCs of its own. I'm not aware of the state of implementation of any of them.

Comment: You cannot multicast on the Internet, except through tunnels. Multicast routing is different than normal IP routing, and every router in the path must have multicast routing enabled, the same multicast mode (SM or DM), and the same multicast policies. This is not possible on the Internet.

Comment: @RonMaupin if multicast isn't a viable option to stream data online, what would be the best alternative? My current approach of creating Datagram Sockets for each listener seems rather wasteful to me.

Comment: Most companies which do this have multiple regional sites with replicated servers. Using something like anycast lets users connect to the nearest (from the perspective of the Internet) server from which to receive the streams. Understand that theses regional sites have very large pipes.

Comment: @RonMaupin based on your answer sounds like my approach might still be the best in my situation, anycast won't be helpful to me because I'm already using geo location to select the server I am streaming from

Comment: You may want to ask this question on [sf] instead of here. The people there have more experience with this sort of thing, but I really wanted to stop you from going down the hole with multicast on the Internet since you can't do that.

Comment: @RonMaupin much appreciated!